# Lightswitch / silverlight remove glyph from datagrid column header

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

Im a newbie to lightswitch and silverlight (ran for the hills on SL v1.0 but as with anything its now coming full circle)

I have seen some examples with XAML and silverlight, and also a couple with datagridview, the issue I have is that Im working with lightswitch and as such there is no XAML :(

I had to fix and issue with a work around for dealing with sorting a grid and resetting the sort order (and there is a LS known issue on this) but now when the user has hit a reset button and the ordering is reset it binds ok and all is hunky dory, I just need to remove the glyph from the column heading. I have access to the grid and can iterate through the columns but don't have a clue at the moment on how to do this....

thanks